# swagger: file path in path parameter

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-2.0

Here is my api requirement

```
GET http://localhost:8080/filePath/{path}
```

For example:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/filePath/home/users/user/one.txt
```

Here is yaml config:

```
parameters:
        - name: path
          in: path
          description: Todo description
          type: string
          required: true
```

But I'm getting 404 error. How can I use file path in path parameter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger: wildcard path parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335178/swagger-wildcard-path-parameters)

Answer (score 3):

OpenAPI 2.0 (Swagger 2.0), 3.0, and 3.1 do not allow you to use slashes in path parameters, so you can't do that. There's an open feature request for this:

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/892